# Group by for DRF Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have `Document` model with `publication_date` field:

```py
class Document(models.Model):
    ...
    publication_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    ...
```

I need to serialize all `Document`s while grouping them by year:

```json
{
    "count": 9,
    "groups": [
        {
            "year": 2020,
            "documents": [...],
        },
        {
            "year": 2019,
            "documents": [...],
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I've tried to use `ListSerializer` with overridden `to_representaion`, but it didn't work out: the reason is that only a single object is being passed to `to_representation`, not the whole queryset.

I have a working example, but it's quite suboptimal:

```py
class DocumentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet:
    ...

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        groups = []
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        years = queryset.annotate(year=ExtractYear("publication_date")) \
                        .values_list("year", flat=True) \
                        .distinct()

        for year in sorted(years, reverse=True):
            documents = queryset.filter(publication_date__year=year)
            groups.append({
                "year": year,
                "documents": self.get_serializer(documents, many=True).data,
            })

        data = {
            "count": queryset.count(),
            "groups": groups,
        }

        return Response(data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Is there a way to do this with DRF List Serializers?
Maybe there are alternatives?
Is it possible to do this faster/better in any way?